# Forcing override of file with template() in Rails generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I have myself a generator that, as part of a set of other operations, needs to set up a model class with a bunch of mixins, defaults, comments, etc.

I want to be using the same `rails g model ...` code (I'm calling `invoke` from my generator), but the problem is that there's a conflict because my template and the model generator's template are trying to splat each other:

```
$ be rails g entry_form karaoke events full_name:string group_name:string
      create  app/controllers/karaokes_controller.rb
      create  app/views/karaokes/show.html.erb
      create  app/views/karaokes/thanks.html.erb
       route  resource :karaoke
      create  app/models/karaoke_entry.rb
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20111004004008_create_karaoke_entries.rb
    conflict    app/models/karaoke_entry.rb
  Overwrite app/models/karaoke_entry.rb?
  (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

Any recommendations how to get around this?

(The best I've come up with is to maybe move my model file creation to the bottom, and find some way to force `template` / `copy_file` to go ahead and overwrite the file without bothering the user, but I can't see any pre-existing way of doing this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `force: true` or `skip: true` to the template call:

```
template "model.rb", "app/models/#{model}.rb", force: true
```

Comment: Have switched to accepting this answer, as Rails has changed since I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

Some group brainstorming turned up a way to work around this problem.

You can't override (in so far as I can tell), but you can tell the model generator to skip files that already exist. This works:

```
# Create the model definition from a template:
template "model.rb", "app/models/#{model}.rb"

# ... Later, get Rails to create everything else:
Rails::Generators.invoke("model", ["Example", "title:string", "--skip"])
```

(I would still welcome a way to allow `template` to override files.)

Comment: It's been a month with no other replies, so I'm accepting my own "answer". :-|

Comment: Even though this is old, I'm adding this comment for anyone coming across this with a search.  The correct answer is to use the "--force" flag, not "--skip".  If the generated file is identical to the existing one, "--force" will OVERRIDE, "--skip" will skip.  See the documentation for Thor [ thor/lib/thor/actions.rb initialize()  https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/lib/thor/actions.rb#L74